# How to create a reusable component with Ionic 3 and Angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I want to create a reusable header to my app. So, I did:

Created the component (app-header):

`app-header.ts`:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: 'app-header.html'
})
export class AppHeaderComponent {

  text: string;

  constructor() {
    console.log('Hello AppHeaderComponent Component');
    this.text = 'Hello World';
  }

}
```

That have the HTML:

`app-header.html`:

```
<div>
  {{text}}
</div>
```

And I've added the `AppHeaderComponent` to `declarations` in `@NgModule`:

```
...

import { AppHeaderComponent } from '../components/app-header/app-header';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    TabsPage,
    AppHeaderComponent
  ],

...
```

I'm using TabsTemplate and I want to add this component in every tab, so, I did on `feed.html` (one of my tabs):

```
<app-header></app-header>

<ion-content>

...
```

But it gives tthe following error:

> Uncaught Error: Template parse errors: 'app-header' is not a known
>   element:
>   1. If 'app-header' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
>   2. If 'app-header' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component
>   to suppress this message. ("  -->
>
> [ERROR ->]

So, I changed `app-header.ts` to:

```
import { Component, NgModule, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: 'app-header.html'
})
@NgModule({
  schemas: [ CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA ]
})
export class AppHeaderComponent {

  text: string;

  constructor() {
    console.log('Hello AppHeaderComponent Component');
    this.text = 'Hello World';
  }

}
```

But the same error still here.

How can I do this?

**Update**:

I'm using Tabs, so, I have:

`tabs.ts`:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { FeedPage } from '../feed/feed';
import { AboutPage } from '../about/about';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'tabs.html'
})
export class TabsPage {

  tabFeed = FeedPage;
  tabAbout= AboutPage;

  constructor() {

  }
}
```

And `tabs.html`:

```
<ion-tabs>
  <ion-tab [root]="tabFeed" tabIcon="paper"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tabAbout" tabIcon="search"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

And each tab load a page, like `feed.html` (quoted in the question)

Code architecture:

[image]

And `components.modules.ts` have:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppHeaderComponent } from './app-header/app-header';
@NgModule({
    declarations: [AppHeaderComponent],
    imports: [],
    exports: [AppHeaderComponent]
})
export class ComponentsModule {}
```

Comment: The error indicates that component wasn't loaded, so CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA isn't helpful. It's unclear in which NgModule module it was declared, and this is important. Consider providing http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: @estus But I specified where I tried to put `CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA` in question... What is the doubt?

Comment: Without MCVE the question is off-topic. The hierarchy of modules is questionable. Also, in your code NgModule with CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA is specified on component class. Of course, it won't work this way. Even if you will get it to work, the primary problem is that the component isn't recognized by compiler. Generally you almost never should use CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA. This error just shouldn't be there.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to remove it from `app.module.ts` since it has been declared in the `ComponentsModule`.

*app.module.ts*

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    TabsPage,
    //AppHeaderComponent <-- need to remove this
  ],
```

After that, you need to `import` the `ComponentsModule` as shown below on the page's `module` where you need it.

*my.module.ts*

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyPage,
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicPageModule.forChild(MyPage),
    ComponentsModule <-- here you need
  ],
})
export class MyPageModule { }
```

Comment: it is a bit late but for me with ionic 3, I had to import ComponentsModule in app.module instead of doing it in myPage.module itself (under "imports")

Comment: Which is very BAD. That means you'll import all the components when the app is being initialized. But for the better performance, you have to import the components where the pages you need to use it @oriuken

Comment: I understand what you mean but I just couldn't make it work importing from the page module. Anyway thanks for the info

Answer (score 2):

This is how `ComponentsModule` should look like otherwise, you won't be able to use ionic wrappers like `ion-grid`, `ion-row` etc.

***components.module.ts***

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {CreatePostComponent} from './create-post/create-post';
import {IonicModule} from "ionic-angular";

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
    CreatePostComponent,
  ],
    imports: [
    IonicModule, <== make sure to import IonicModule
  ],
    exports: [
    CreatePostComponent,
  ]
})
export class ComponentsModule {}
```

and then after this, you would wanna put `ComponentsModule` inside imports array of any other component's `module.ts` file where you want to use it. Here, for example, I want to use `CreatePostComponent` inside my newsfeed page (ionic page).

***newsfeed.module.ts***

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    NewsfeedPage,
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicPageModule.forChild(NewsfeedPage),
    ComponentsModule
  ],
})
```

and voila, you can then use your `CreatePostComponent` selector (create-post in my case) inside `newsfeed.html`.

```
<create-post></create-post>
```